# right detail of static tableview not visible in IOS 8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios8

I have a `static UITableView`. Some cells are set to `right detail`. 
I made UILabel IBOUTLETS for all the right labels and connected them in storyboard. In my viewWillAppear I set the text of the UILabel.

Here is the problem. When my view apppears my text on the label is not visible. But when I touch the cell. The label becomes visible.

This is an `IOS 8 problem only.` Can someone help me with this.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

There is some bug in Interface builder in Xcode 6.

Change **Style** of Table View Cell in IB to *Basic* and then to *Right Detail* again.
It should work then.